# A cache which knows about reachability

Tags: java, caching, guava, weak-references, soft-references

I'd like a cache with some maximum retaining capacity of N. I'm allowing it to hold up to N objects which would otherwise be eligible for GC. Now, if my application itself currently holds N+1 strong references to objects which it's previously added to the cache, I want the cache to hold N+1 too. Why? Because the cache won't be keeping this N+1th object from being collected any longer than it would be otherwise, and I'm fine trading a bigger hash table for more cache hits.

Another way of putting it, I'd like an object cache which retains all objects added to it while they remain strongly reachable, and also retains enough non-strongly reachable objects to keep its size == N.

### Example

We have a cache created with N=100. Size starts at 0. 150 objects are added, size is 150. 100 of those objects become non-strongly reachable (weakly, softly, whatever). Cache evicts 50 of those and keeps 50, size is 100. 49 more strongly reachable objects are added. Size is still 100 but now 99 of them are strongly reachable and only one is non-strongly reachable. What happened is 49 older, non-strongly reachable objects were replaced with the new 49 because the new ones were strongly reachable.

### Motivation

I suspect it's actually an intuitive thing to want for a number of use cases. Typically the cache's capacity trades off cache hit probability for a guarantee for maximum memory usage. Knowing about the reachability of the objects it holds, a cache could deliver higher cache hit probability without changing its maximum memory usage guarantee.

### The Trouble

I'm worried it's not possible on the JVM. I'm hoping to be told otherwise, but if you know for a fact it's not possible I'll accept that answer too if there's rationale.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the entries to a LinkedHashMap configured as an LRU or FIFO cache. You can have a WeakHashMap as well.  If you add the key to both maps, the LHM will prevent cleanup even though its in the WHM.  Once the LHM discards the key, it may or may not be in the WHM.

e.g

```
private final int retainedSize;
private final Map<K,V> lruMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>(16, 0.7f, true) {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<K, V> eldest) {
        return size() > retainedSize;
    }
};
private final Map<K,V> weakMap = new WeakHashMap<K, V>();

public void put(K k, V v) {
    lruMap.put(k, v);
    weakMap.put(k,v);
}

public V get(K k) {
    V v = lruMap.get(k);
    return v == null ? weakMap.get(k) : v;
}
```

One of the reason to do this is that a WeakHashMap is like to be clearer all at once, so you hit rate can drop very sharply.  This approach ensures that after you have been hit with a Full GC, your performance won't drop too much as you try to catch up. ;)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Doesn't quite work as desired. In the example I gave, if the 100 that go weak are the last 100 added, your size will be 150 whereas it should be 100.

Comment: So you have two sizes, the size of the strong keyed items and the size of the weak keyed elements?  Is there a reason for this given that weak keyed elements are cleaned up on the next GC anyway. i.e. removing them from the map won't save any memory.

Comment: If you don't like Peter's solution (which can be modified to use Guava's `Cache` if you need more configuration options, or maybe less contention), I guess you want a manual management, where you explicitely tell the cache that you're not using some value anymore, which means reference counting, which in turn is particularily error-prone. I'd stick with the JVM's automatic memory management. As Peter says, until the weak values have been collected by the garbage collector, you might as well still be able to use them. Why does the cache **have** to be cleaned instantly?

Comment: @BrianHarris Its worth nothing that an object is ONLY cleaned up on a GC. Attempting to clean it up before a GC occur will not free any space.  This means manually removing entries in a WeakHashMap before a GC occur pointless if your aim is to save space IMHO

Comment: The reason this doesn't quite work is that the LHM may be holding strong references to otherwise weakly reachable entries and meanwhile the WHM is holding strongly reachable objects. As stated in my comment above, if the last 100 added become weakly reachable external to the cache, they will not be collected because the LHM is holding them. This means the cache has those 100, plus the 50 in the WHM which remain strongly reachable external to the cache. That's a size of 150 which will not decrease to 100 on the next GC cycle. The cache is keeping 50 more entries in memory than it is allowed to.

Comment: If you want to retain 50 but you set it to retain 100, it won't know you really meant to retain 50. I am confused as to what the problem is. If you set it to retain 50 and you add 100, it may grow up to 100 and on the next GC it will be 50.

Comment: I know it's a somewhat confusing request, I tried to be clear with an example. I highlighted where your solution behaves different to the example in my comments here. How many otherwise-weakly reachable cache entries the cache retains should depend on how many otherwise-strongly reachable cache entries the cache is holding. Back to the example, if it holds 100 otherwise strongly reachable entries then it should strongly hold 0 more otherwise non-strongly reachable entries. If it holds 10 otherwise-strongly reachable entries, it should strongly hold 90 otherwise non-strongly reachable entries.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to limit the number of entries in the weak hash map. Only the number of entries in the strong map matters and that is is set by you to what ever value you want. Can you confirm you understand that the number of entries in the weak map has no impact on free memory. Removing an entry from the weak map or not adding it to the weak map will make no real difference to the free memory. Can you say why you want to limit the total number of entries?

Comment: I don't care about limiting entries in the weak map. Agree with you that only the number of entries in the LHM matters. And that's the problem here, the LHM may be keeping alive entries that it shouldn't be. When 150 elements are added, the first 50 spill over into the WHM. Great. Later, the last 100 I added become weakly referenced external to the cache. These 100 are sitting inside the LHM, strongly referenced. That is a problem, this cache should only strongly reference 50 of those weakly reachable entries *because* it already has 50 strongly reachable entries sitting in the WHM for its 100

Comment: If you set the retainedSize to 50, it will only keep the most recently used 50, If you add 100, it will discard the 50 least recently used. If you add 1000000, it will discard the least recently used 999950 (which all end up in the weak hashmap until the next GC) In short, the presence of the weak hashmap doesn't change the fact the LHM will only have at most 50 entries.

Comment: "These 100 are sitting inside the LHM, strongly referenced" This won't happen because you set the limit to 50.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16567/discussion-between-brian-harris-and-peter-lawrey)

Answer (score 0):

Check out `WeakHashMap`. Stale references will be removed automatically. Before putting you could check if size exceeds your threshold and skip putting in a new value.

Alternativley you could override put and discard the value if the size is above your threshold.

This method would work as you propose, since you do not need a cache eviction policy you could just skip putting in new elements if the size is greater than your threshold.

Comment: The crux of his question, really, is how to calculate the threshold -- because the actual threshold is determined by how many objects in the cache are strongly referenced elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you need the threshold at all? WeakHashMap evicts all entries that are stale

Comment: *WeakHashMap evicts all entries that are stale* -- which is not what Brian wants.  He wants to **keep** the weak references if the cache still has room in it after allowing for the space the strong references use. e.g. cache size = 100, there are 70 strongly referenced items in the cache, so allow 30 weakly referenced items to stay in the cache (in case they're used again "soon") - but kick them out if more strong references are added.

Comment: And "if size exceeds your threshold and skip putting in a new value" does no good: You might end with 100 old never more referenced objects in your cache and cache no useful objects until the GC comes. Of course, there's no guarantee that caching the new objects is better, but most of time it is.

Comment: @Stephen I just don't see how they could be used again ever. Once it's gone stale it's stale. The weak hash map will not resize when removing keys so it would not matter anyways

Comment: @maaartinus That would require you to think of a cache strategy, like LFU / LRU. The question did not state any priority

Comment: @jontro: With weak keys you're right: When they become unreachable, then the entries become completely useless indeed (unless you use `equals` rather than `==` for the lookup, which is rarely useful). However, there are things like [CacheBuilder.weakValues](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html) where holding some subset of keys strongly can make sense.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand what you are saying. The OP wants to release the object if there are no "other" strong references and the cache is in need of space. However I guess there is no way of determining this and the practical use of this would be very limited. If you can post your real use case maybe we can help you think of a different way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want makes sense, but maybe not that much. Let's assume that the values are quite big (some kilobytes), otherwise the caching of the elsewhere strongly hold values may get expensive too. Ignore this overhead, your cache indeed has constant memory costs. However, I'm not sure if this goal is worth pursuing -- I'm rather interested how to use about constant amount of memory for the whole program (I don't want to leave too much memory unused and in no case I want to start swapping).

Idea: The cache should use *registered* weak (or soft) references.<sup>1</sup> You use another thread calling `ReferenceQueue.remove()` in loop and checking some condition<sup>2</sup>. Depending on it, you either remove the corresponding entry from the cache (as Guava does) or you resurrect the value via `reference.get()` and thus protect it temporarily from being garbage collected.<sup>3</sup>. This should work, but it costs some time during each GC run.

---

<sup>1</sup>Overriding `finalize()` would do as well. **Actually, it looks like this is the only way as `reference.get()` when enqueued always returns null so it can't be used for resurrection.**

<sup>2</sup>The condition should be sort of "do it 100 times per GC run".

<sup>3</sup>I'm not sure the GC really works this way, but I suppose it does. If not, then you could use a copy of the value instead. I'm also unsure what happens when the value loses strong reachability the next time, but again, this is surely solvable (e.g., create a new Reference).